# Cannot Resolve Method makeText(Anonymous Android.view.View.OnclickListener,java.land.string , int)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd9xB.png)
Please Help Me I'm A Beginner Developer And Thank you <3 .

Comment: Use `MainActivity.this` instead of `this` as the first argument in the `Toast.makeText()` call. Also, please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: Thank You The problem Is Solved Thank you Very Much